# Куда в приставке "одно-" падает ударение при перечислении "одно- двух- трехместный"?

Tags: орфоэпия, приставка

Подскажите, при перечислении "одно- двух- трехместный", на какую букву падает ударение в первой приставке "одно-"? 
И есть ли в слове "одноместный" второстепенное ударение, и если есть, то на какую букву оно падает? 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Главный словарь в подобных случаях - Русское словесное ударение.

По поводу побочного, более слабого ударения в слове "одноместный" словарь помалкивает, что означает: нету его.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Одно-, двух- и трёхместный* - ударение на каждом слове, а в последнем, полном, их аж два: на "ё" (слабое) и на "е" (основное).

В сокращённом "одно-" ударение на второе *о*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ударения проставлены. КРАСНЫМ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Есть ли какое-то правило, согласно которому ударение в "одно-" на второе о?

Comment: "Одно-" - это не приставка, а корень. Слово "одноместный" - сложное слово, двухкорневое, с соединительной гласной *о*. См.: https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9 Я дополнила ответ цитатой из словаря, но не вполне согласна с "первой частью сложных слов", это спорный момент.